# How do i pass methods to a constructor which takes Action<T1,T2>

Tags: c#

Hello i am getting a syntax error with passing my two methods to a constructor that takes two actions, not sure how to fix it.

The constructor takes two arguments:

```
Action<ControlPoint<T>, pt> _callback1;
Action<ControlPoint<T>, pt> _callback2;
public Test(in Action<ControlPoint<T>, pt> callback1, in Action<ControlPoint<T>, pt> callback2)
{
    _callback1 = callback1;
    _callback2 = callback2;
}
```

And i am creating an instance like this:

```
Test test = new Test(fnc1,fnc2); // error occurs here
```

With the following function definitions:

```
void fnc1(in ControlPoint<pt> ctrPt, in pt pt){}
void fnc2(in ControlPoint<pt> ctrPt, in pt pt){}
```

However i get this error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'in Action<ControlPoint<pt>, pt>'
```

What am i getting wrong?

Comment: You don't need `in` on the parameters.

Comment: Ah, i was using `in` to prevent accidental changes to the reference. Strange it doesn't allow them.

Comment: @madreflection: That's the entire problem, the delegate requires pass-by-value and the function is pass-by-reference.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I know that. I just consider this more of a typo. I don't like answering silly mistakes like this.

Comment: Why does it not allow `in` ? I use it a lot to enforce stricter code such as not changing the reference. Seems unnecessary to not allow it.

Comment: Then you're over-using it. `in` isn't needed on reference types because the reference is copied. It's only useful on value types where you're taking a reference to the value, and you want to prevent modification of the referenced value.

Comment: But using `in` means i cannot do `myObj = null` or change it to something else entirely. Which is why i use it a lot to make it clear it's reference should'nt be changed.

Comment: @WDUK: Without `in`, such changes won't affect the caller.  The function has its own reference to the same object.  It can update the reference it owns, but the caller's reference won't change.

Comment: `in` is `ref` with compiler-enforced assignment prevention. If you wouldn't use `ref`, you shouldn't use `in`.

Comment: `in` is telling the compiler - pass in a reference to this reference type, but don't let it be modified. It's functionally the same as _not_ using `in` since the reference would get passed by value.

Comment: Oh so actions create their own copy of the reference?

Comment: Because `Action` is a reference type, yes. The _value_ of the reference is used by the called method. If you change the value within the called method, the caller never knows it.

Comment: A key takeaway is that you're abusing `in` and your code needs to be scrubbed. When you assign a non-`ref` (again, `in` is a special case of `ref`, so is `out`) reference type parameter within a method, it already doesn't change the caller's reference. You've been protecting against nothing.

Answer (score -1):

this is because your `fnc1` and `fnc2` are instance methods and cannot be called without an instance `this` pointer.  One solution is to change them to `static`, at which point you should not see that error anymore.

Note: This is just an educated guess since you have not provided a complete code example.